# How do I express a range of array positions in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How could I express:

```
    From Array[0-9][0-9] print Player
    From Array[0-9][10-79] print blankSpace
    From Array[10-19[0-29] print blankSpace
    From Array[10-19][30-39] print tree1
```

Etc.

If it's not obvious I'm trying to print a game map where you can control the Player by moving it over "tiles" (Each one is equal to 10x10 of array positions or char spaces if you prefer) but I can't seem to find any way to "select" a range of positions in arrays instead of just two positions.

If I said [0][9] for player example it would print the player character on that one position but seeing as I'm printing in type char. it would only be equal to '!' for example. I'm meant to print a square of '!'s for example which would take up 10x10 chars.

Then using my logic, if I could "select" a range of array positions I could print out a pre-defined array of characters making up my overall character's look using the Player() function. Same for the blankSpaces and tree1 etc.

Any help/criticism/sarcastic banter on my fail logic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no built-in way to work with ranges quite the way you've described it, but there are loops, which come pretty close :-)

```
for (int j = 0; j != 10; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        PrintPlayerAt(j, i);
    }
}
```

It looks like you're going to end up "repainting" a whole rectangular region, though, and making the cursor jump around in (what I'm assuming is a console/command line) window is non-trivial. So I suggest changing your logic away from the object-oriented "print *this* *here*" to a locality-oriented "when we're *here*, print *this*. Some pseudo-code to clarify:

```
for (int j = 0; j != 20; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 80; ++i) {
        if ((0 <= j && j < 10) && (0 <= i && i < 10)) {
            PrintPlayer();
        }
        else if ((10 <= j && j < 20) && (30 <= i && i < 40)) {
            PrintTree();
        }
        // ...
        else {
            PrintBlankSpace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is so simple, why I didn't think of this sooner is beyond me.

Comment: Helpful but I'm sure that if I wanted to move the character outside of what is viewable, eg. a bigger map than what the console allows on at one time this could be messy? Or if it's at least possible this new way, clarification would be incredibly useful. Thanks for your effort. :)  (From a noob learning programming)

Comment: @user: Well, ideally you don't hardcode ranges into the loop. One cleaner way would be to create a buffer (array) that's large enough to hold the whole "logical" map (it may be bigger than the displayed area), and fill the cells with the characters that should be displayed on screen. Then, when the player moves (or whatever), you update this buffer (only the player part). Printing out the map is then trivial; simply loop over the rectangle that's currently visible and print out each character in it. You can even create multiple buffers (e.g. 1 for characters and 1 for the map) and have layers!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no built-in way to do this in C++. You can use a nested loop to iterate across the array though.